# Strange thing with apply/merge-with, in Clojure

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

Who can explain me this fact:

```
user> ((partial merge-with +) {:a 1} {:a 2})
{:a 3}
user> (apply (partial merge-with +) ({:a 1} {:a 2}))
nil
```

Why do I get `nil` in the second case?
What is wrong with the second line?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The expression

```
({:a 1} {:a 2})
```

evaluates to `nil`. Maps in Clojure are functions which takes a key and returns the corresponding value. The expression

```
(let [f {:a 1}]
  (f {:a 2}))
```

which is equivalent to `({:a 1} {:a 2})` tries to lookup the **key** `{:a 2}` in the **map** `{:a 1}` and since there is no such key in the map `nil` is returned.

Going back to your original problem, all you have to do is to change the list `({:a 1} {:a 2})` to a vector `[{:a 1} {:a 2}]` and it will work as expected. Note also that you don't need `partial` in this particular case, `(apply merge-with + [{:a 1} {:a 3}])` will work just fine.

Answer (score 3):

In the second case, when you `({:a 1} {:a 2})`, as maps act as functions which get values from them, what you're doing is equivalent to `(get {:a 1} {:a 2})` and, as `{:a 2}` is not a key in `{:a 1}`, you get `nil`. Then, aplying the function over nil gets nil.

What you have to do is either quote the list, such as not evaluate it as a function application

```
user=> (apply (partial merge-with +) '({:a 1} {:a 2}))
{:a 3}
```

or use a vector (which is more idiomatic in clojure)

```
user=> (apply (partial merge-with +) [{:a 1} {:a 2}])
{:a 3}
```

Juan Manuel